# jQuery: Check if a element exists (which could possibly be added through ajax)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom, exists

I already know how to check elements that are there when the document is ready:

```
jQuery.fn.exists = function () { 
  return jQuery(this).length > 0; 
}
```

But this method doesn’t know elements that are added with AJAX. Does anybody know how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method does once the ajax is loaded and appended to the DOM. 
You could rewrite it a bit:

```
jQuery.existsin = function (what, where) { 
  return jQuery(where).find(what).length > 0; 
}
```

The you could on ajax success :

```
function(data, status){
  if(jQuery.existsin('selector', data)){
    //do foo
  }
}
```

Comment: would it be smart to specify "body" as a "default where" ?

Comment: @Eivind please let me know the selector here.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/livequery/